# Not able to uninstall managed package

Tags: managed-package, page-layout, error, lightning-page, uninstall

I am trying to uninstall a CPQ related managed package and I am facing issues during the uninstall. There were about 100 errors, and I have addressed most of them by deleting the impacted components. The last error message that I am getting is below.

```
Component Type      Name             Problem
Custom Field        ProposalId       Component is in use by another component in your organization. Proposal_Page
```

I have removed the field ProposalId from page layout that is associated with the lightning page Proposal_Page. However, I am still getting the same error.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The field ProposalId was on two different objects in the managed pakcage. I removed the related list of both objects from the classic and lightning pages and then the uninstall worked.